# Does adding a new object to Session with an existing key replace the older object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's say I put an object to the session variable with a certain key. Later I put another object with the same key. What I am going to have at the end?

```
Session["keyA"] = objectA;
```

Another request later

```
Session["keyA"] = objectB;
```

**objectA** and **objectB** are both `List<T>`. The result is a **objectC** that contains rows from **objectA** and **objectB**.

My understanding was that when you put a new object with an existing, the new object replace the older one.

Maybe I have another bug somewhere else that's causing this behavior, but so far this is what I'm experiencing.

Why is this occurring?

Comment: define *replaces*: replace the reference (pointer), replace the memory itself (like copying over), ...? Where is `objectC` in your example, how exactly do you access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something else going on somewhere in your code if using the assignment operator causes behavior like that. There's no reason setting `Session["keyA"]` to `objectB` would result in it being combined with `objectA`.

`Session` is, for the purposes of this answer, a `Dictionary<string, object>`. Try running this code:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var objectA = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
var objectB = new List<string> { "d", "e", "f" };
d["keyA"] = objectA;
d["keyA"] = objectB;
if (d["keyA"] == objectB) {
    Console.WriteLine("has objectB at 'keyA'");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("has something else, I don't know");
}
```

<sup>[also here](http://csharppad.com/gist/208924d79ced927bcb65ec10284a46b4)</sup>

This should write "has objectB at 'keyA'" in the console.

If it doesn't something has gone horribly wrong and you should immediately pull the plug from your computer, remove any batteries, and dispose of the whole thing in a safe manner.

Comment: Funny?? Loool! I was just trying to save myself trips to the database. Thank you so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding was that when you put a new object with an existing,
>   the new object replace the older one.

No, it won't replace the older one. As you know when you store an object into a variable, and then assigned it to another variable they both are the same, because it's just the **reference address** the object in the memory.

```
var obj1 = new Object();
var obj2 = obj1;

// this line just set value of obj2 into null and obj1 is still works
obj2 = null;
```

In your scenario there is nothing different from what I said for above code:

```
Session["keyA"] = objectA;

// this won't replace `objectA` with objectB
// only store the reference of objectB in the dictionary with keyA
Session["keyA"] = objectB;
```

> Maybe I have another bug somewhere else that's causing this behavior,
>   but so far this is what I'm experiencing.

I'm sure there is another bug somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.